# Render View or Block not Working in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, blocks

So i have made a view and a block for a carousel. 
I want to call this view or block in my template. (**panels-pane.tpl.php**).

I have tried to call the view with this function :

```
<?php $view = views_embed_view('carousel', 'carousel-block_1'); print $view; ?>
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Variable $view is NULL

I also tried to call a block in this template file with this function :

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', 'carousel-block_1');
var_dump($block); // Empty ;s
```

Also not working..

The Delta ID is right. See Screenshot below for more information.

Do i something wrong?

[image]

Full page code with other view render (also not working):

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @file panels-pane.tpl.php
 */

?>

<?php if ($pane_prefix): ?>
  <?php print $pane_prefix; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div
  class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $id; ?> <?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if ($admin_links): ?>
    <?php print $admin_links; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <div class="pane-content">
    <?php $view = views_embed_view('downloads', 'downloads-product_downloads'); print $view;     var_dump($view); ?>
    <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
    <?php if ($title): ?>
    <<?php print $title_heading; ?><?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <?php print $title; ?>
  </<?php print $title_heading; ?>>
<?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <?php if ($feeds): ?>
    <div class="feed">
      <?php print $feeds; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>


  <?php print render($content); ?>
</div>

<?php if ($links): ?>
  <div class="links">
    <?php print $links; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($more): ?>
  <div class="more-link">
    <?php print $more; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php if ($pane_suffix): ?>
  <?php print $pane_suffix; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope views will never use ***hypens***. May be you typed wrong.

**Views always use underscores.**

```
<?php $view = views_embed_view('carousel', 'carousel-block_1'); print $view; ?>
```

I think it should be

```
<?php $view = views_embed_view('carousel', 'carousel_block_1'); print $view; ?>
```

As per your template.php

```
<?php $view = views_embed_view('downloads', 'downloads_product_downloads'); print $view;     var_dump($view); ?>
```

Comment: Hi Nagarjuna! Sorry but this is not the solution :(

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works:

```
print views_embed_view('view_name','machine_name', $parameter);
```

In case you are wondering, [this is the machine_name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

`$parameter` is optional

Example:

```
$parameter = 1;
print views_embed_view('hello_world','block_1', $parameter);
```

---

So for your case, assuming your view is literally called/named Carousel, then it's probably:

```
<?php $view = views_embed_view('carousel', 'block_1'); print $view; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your view is working. I have similar template code that works.

Comment: Hi Lars, Thanks for your answer but the view is working fine. Tried it also with other views but still no result.